# data base job scheduler time limit

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

i have many schedule jobs some are working after 15 minutes ,some are after 1 hour and some are after 5 seconds ,how can i manage them between 6:am to 7:pm.
all executes at their own time but between 6:am to 7:pm.
i am highly waiting of your kind response.
exp

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'UPDATE_UPLOADREQUESTSTATS_JOB',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'CON_UPDATE_UPLOADREQUEST_STATS',
   start_date         =>  '30-OCT-18 12.10.00 PM Asia/Riyadh',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=SECONDLY; INTERVAL=6', 
   end_date           =>  '31-DEC-25 07.00.00 PM Asia/Riyadh',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   enabled             =>   TRUE,
   comments           =>  'TEVS JOB');
END;
```

Comment: Is this the procedure UPDATE_UPLOADREQUESTSTATS_JOB which is calling  the other procedures or you have scheduled all the other procedures differently using Oracle scheduler ?

Comment: its just the job name we can keep ABC,In job_action "CON_UPDATE_UPLOADREQUEST_STATS" this is the actual procedure which job calling

Comment: you can use Oracle Scheduler Job Chain, to schedule the jobs to be run in parallel or to be executed depending upon some conditions,please chekc this link  for more info, they have a good example.https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2020/06/16/parallel-execution-of-pl-sql-procedures/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my best way to handle this situation.If you want to execute this proc after each 3 minutes between 6:00 am to 7:00 pm we can use like

```
    BEGIN
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
       job_name           =>  'UPDATE_UPLOADREQUESTSTATS_JOB',
       job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
       job_action         =>  'CON_UPDATE_UPLOADREQUEST_STATS',
       start_date         =>  'TRUNC(SYSDATE)',
       repeat_interval    => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19;BYMINUTE=3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57', 
       end_date           =>  '31-DEC-25 07.00.00 PM Asia/Riyadh',
       auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
       enabled             =>   TRUE,
       comments           =>  'TEVS JOB');
    END;
```